# Laravel: Mostrar datos de 2 tablas diferentes en un formulario

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Problema: El cliente tiene el siguiente formulario el cual lo que hace es mostrar los datos de imagen; pero no sé como mostrar (mandar a llamar) el último dato que le pertenece a otra tabla (CategoriaCurso)

[image: Imagen visual del documento]

**Modelo Constancia:**

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Constancia extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'rfc',
                                    'curp',
                                    'nombre',
                                    'apellidos',
                                    'telefono',
                                    'correo',
                                    'ocupacion_especifica',
                                    'puesto',
                                    'fecha_exp',
                                    'fecha_ven',
                                    'razon_social',
                                    'rfc_empresa',
                                    'representante_legal',
                                    'representante_trabajadores',
                                    'duracion_horas',
                                    'folio',
                                    'secuencia_folio',
                                    'curso_id',
                                    'foto_id',
                                    'signatario',
                                    
                                ];

    public function scopeFecha($query, $fecha)
    {
        if ($fecha) {
            return $query->where('fecha_exp', 'LIKE', "%$fecha%");
        }
    }

    // public function curso()
    // {
    //  return $this->belongsTo(CategoriaCurso::class);
    //  // return $this->belongsToMany('App\CategoriaCurso', 'curso_id');
    //  // return $this->belongsToMany('App\CategoriaCurso');
    // }
}
```

**Modelo: CategoriaGrupo**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoriaCurso extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['clave', 'nombre_curso', 'area_tematica', 'duracion'];

   public function cursos()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Constancia::class);

    }
    public function area()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AreaTematica::class);

    }
}
```

Finalmente este es el código que tengo en el archivo buscarF.blade.php

```
@extends('Layouts.app')
@section('titulo','Buscar Folio')
@section('subtitulo', '')
@section('content')


<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card bg-light" style="max-width: 33rem;">
                  <div class="card-header" style="justify-content: center; display: flex;">
                        <h1>Resultados</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Folio:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->folio                 }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">RFC:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->rfc                 }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">CURP:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->curp                 }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Nombre:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->nombre                 }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Apellidos:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->apellidos                 }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Expedicion:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->fecha_exp                }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Vencimiento:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->fecha_ven                }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Duracion:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->duracion_horas.' '.'Horas'            }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput">Curso:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ $constancia[0]->nombre_curso                 }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                      </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
           <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('buscarFolio') }}" role="button" style="background: #21ADB5; margin-top: 5px;">Ir al Buscador</a>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-auto">
           <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" role="button" style="background: #21ADB5; margin-top: 5px;;">Ir a Inicio</a>
        </div>-->
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Soy muy novato y llevo ya 3 días intentando todo y hoy quise pedir ayuda :(

Si necesitan el código de controlador aquí también se los dejo (PD: la programación la hizo otra persona que sabe sobre ello, pero ya no está con nosotros)

Migraciones: [constancias](https://pastebin.pl/view/506090c6)

Migraciones2: [Categoria Cursos](https://pastebin.pl/view/1b578257)

Archivo: [ConstanciaController.php](https://pastebin.pl/view/890c3304)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Por favor, léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio. Dices que eres muy novato en programación, y que el código lo realizó otra persona, y por lo tanto tus intentos han salido mal. Aquí no hacemos código a medida, lo siento, para eso estan los profesionales que cobran por ello. Si te damos una solución (quizas alguno te la da) no estoy convencido que te ayudemos en nada, porque seguirás sin saber programar y tan solo la pegaras para solucionar tu problema. Tu pregunta no está basada en un [example], sino en un problema con tu código de producción.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar tus migraciones?

Comment: Listo amigo, agregado las migraciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es revisar si tiene las 2 tablas relacionadas mediante llaves, luego de haber confirmado que si existe la relación busca el model **Principal (Constancia)** y crear un metodo que te de el acceso a la tabla relacionada.

Método

```php
public function constancias(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Constancia::class, 'aca colocas el valor que se relacion con la otra tabla, que sería curso_id');
}
```

Ahora te diriges al modelo secundario (CategoriaCurso) y agregas el siguiente metodo:

```php
public function cursoscategorias(){
 return $this->hasMany(CategoriaCurso::class, 'id -> este es el valor de la llave primaria del modelo CategoriaCurso');
}
```

Estos métodos nos permiten tomar los valores de la tabla `CategoriaCurso` ya que mediante el método le estamos indicando la relación que existe entre ambas tablas.

Por ultimo, en la vista de formulario para mostrar el valor del curso pones `$constancia[0]->constancias->y el valor del campo que guarda el nombre del curso`.

Comment: En el controlador no se toca nada? Ya que realicé lo que comentaste y sigo teniendo el mismo resultado amigo.

Comment: Hola Nichael, intenté lo que comentaste y no pude resolver el problema amigo.

Answer (score 0):

ya que realizaste los pasos de la respuesta anterior lo unico que debes hacer es llamar la relación en tu controlador deber tener algo como esto:

```
$constancias = Constancia::with('cursos')->get();
```

y en la vista accedes al nombre o cualquier otra propiedad de esa relacion de esta forma:

```
foreach($constancias as $constancia){
  echo $constancia->cursos->name
}
```